# Javascript, Getting NaN, not sure why

Tags: javascript

My task is to make a stack computer without using an array to implement the stack. When a number is entered it goes onto the top of the stack. When an operation is entered, the previous 2 numbers are operated on by the operation and the result is pushed onto the top of the stack. The  push and pop on the stack seems to work but am getting NaN when I try performing the operations. I'm still relatively new to programming so I don't know where to go from here.

**html:**

```
<input type="numberbox" id="number" value="0" />
<input type="button" onclick="putonstack();" value="Push to Stack" />
<br/> Please select operand:
<select id="operand">
          <option value="+">+</option>
          <option value="-">-</option>
          <option value="*">*</option>
          <option value="/">/</option>
        </select>
<br/>
<input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="calculate();" />
<div id="output1">

</div>
<div id="output" />
```

**script:**

```
function LinkedList() {

  this.head = null;
  this.tail = null;
  this.length = 0;
}

function Node(value) {
  this.data = value;
  this.next = null;
  this.prev = null;
  this.content = null;
}
LinkedList.prototype.nodeAt = function(position) {
  var currentNode = this.tail,
    length = this.length,
    count = 1,
    message = {
      failure: 'Failure: non-existent node in this list.'
    };

  if (length === 0 || position < 1 || position > length) {
    throw new Error(message.failure);
  }

  while (count < position) {
    currentNode = currentNode.previous;
    count++;
  }

  return currentNode;
};
LinkedList.prototype.pop = function(position) {
  var node = this.nodeAt(position);

  if (node.prev) {
    node.prev.next = node.next;
  } else {
    this.head = node.next;
  }

  if (node.next) {
    node.next.prev = node.prev;
  } else {
    this.tail = node.prev;
  }

  this.length--;


  return node;
};

LinkedList.prototype.push = function(_content) {
  var node = new Node();
  node.content = _content;

  if (this.head === null) {
    this.head = node;
    this.length = 1;
    return node;
  }

  if (this.tail === null) {
    this.tail = node;
    this.tail.prev = this.head;
    this.head.next = this.tail;
    this.length++;

    return node;
  }

  this.tail.next = node;
  node.prev = this.tail;
  this.tail = node;
  return node;
};
LinkedList.prototype.print = function() {

  if (this.head === null) return "Empty List";
  var string = "";
  var node = this.head;
  while (node !== null) {
    string += node.content + " ";
    node = node.next;
  }

  return string;
};
var aList = new LinkedList();

function putonstack() {

  var c = document.getElementById("number").value;
  aList.push(c);
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = " ";
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = aList.print();
}

function calculate() {
  var operand = document.getElementById("operand").value;

  try {

    if (aList.length < 2) {
      throw "There must be at least 2 numbers to perform operation";
    } else {
      var a = parseFloat(aList.tail.prev);
      var b = parseFloat(aList.tail);
      var answer = 0;

      for (var i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
        aList.pop();
      }

      if (operand == "+") {
        answer = a + b;
        aList.push(answer);
        document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = " ";
        document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = aList.print();
      } else if (operand == "-") {
        answer = a - b;
        aList.push(answer);
        document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = " ";
        document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = aList.print();
      } else if (operand == "*") {
        answer = a * b;
        aList.push(answer);
        document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = " ";
        document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = aList.print();
      } else if (operand == "/") {
        answer = a / b;
        aList.push(answer);
        document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = " ";
        document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = aList.print();
      }
    }
  } catch (err) {
    document.getElementById("ouput").innerHTML = +err;
    return;
  }


}
```

Thanks for any help or advice you can give.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to do a parseFloat from an object. You should to from the content property.

Wrong code:

```
var a = parseFloat(aList.tail.prev);
var b = parseFloat(aList.tail);
```

Correct code:

```
var a = parseFloat(aList.tail.prev.content);
var b = parseFloat(aList.tail.content);
```

Comment: Made the changes, and it worked as far as geting rid of the NaN. Thank you. Now the program only performs the operation the first time you hit the button, every time after that it throws an error.  Sorry if the questions seem obvious, I've only been doing this about 3 weeks now.